# What the meaning of each question? (What about do they ask?)

Tags: questions

1) What **is** the time?

2) What the time **is it**?

3) What **is** the movie?

4) What the movie **is it**?

5) What the movie **is**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all of the questions are phrased correctly.

> 1) What **is** the time?
>
> 2) What the time **is it**?

These both mean the same thing: What is the time now? Number 2 should be "What time is it?", without "the".

> 3) What **is** the movie?
>
> 4) What the movie **is it**?

This sounds like you are asking about the movie itself. A better way to phrase it might be, "What movie is it" or  "**Which** movie is it?". This means, "What is the name/title of the movie?".  Again, number 4 should not have "the".

> 5) What the movie **is**?

This is not a correct sentence. Depending on what you are trying to ask, you can say one of the above if you are asking for the movie name, or "What is the movie about?" if you want to know the general movie subject.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i want to ask about the meaning of 'movie' in general or the movie with the title 'the'?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you rephrase please?

Comment: What if I want to ask a question about 1) a meaning 'movie' (e.g. What is a movie?) AND 2) about the movie with a title 'The' (e.g. What is 'The' movie) 'The' is a title (name of the movie)

Comment: 1) Correct, you'd say, "What is a movie?". 2) If a movie had a title "The" that I wanted to know more about, I would say, "What is "The" about?"

Answer (score 0):

2 and 4 are not proper English. 
Number 1 is correctly asking the time of day, and # number two can be reworded without "the" in the sentence. What time is it?.
Number 3 is ok for people whose first language is English cause they would understand that your asking what is the name of the movie. To learn English it is improper because you are really answering the question in the question. 
-what is the movie? Well the "movie" is "what" . Properly used would be "What is the movie called" or "What is the movie name" 
Number 5 is also wrong and relates to number three.

Comment: What If I want to ask about a definition of 'time' OR a definition (meaning) of 'movie'?